# Nftables does not work as expected to block with meter

Tags: linux, networking, nftables

Goal:
Account for excess packets whose rate source IP and destination port are greater than 200 packets per second, example:

1s to 2s:
IP 1.1.1.1 to MyServer:80 
[This happens 201 times in second 1]

```
table netdev filter {
    set whitelist {
        type ipv4_addr
        elements = { 186.248.79.100 }
    }

    set blocklist {
        type ipv4_addr
        size 65535
        flags dynamic,timeout
        timeout 30s
    }

    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device "eth0" priority -450; policy accept;
        ip saddr @whitelist accept
        ip daddr 10.0.0.192 jump input
        ip daddr != 10.0.0.192 jump forward
    }

    chain http {
        ip saddr 191.185.17.156 counter
        meter http size 65535 { ip saddr . tcp dport limit rate over 200/second } add @blocklist { ip saddr } counter
    }

    chain forward { }

    chain input {
        tcp dport vmap { 8000 : jump portainer, 9443 : jump portainer }
        tcp dport vmap { 80 : jump http }
    }
}
```

The problem is within the http chain, that is, I made 20 http requests to the server (my public source IP is 191.185.17.156) the accept counter shows that there are 200 packets in total (including tcp tree way handshake, ack etc), until then it's normal, see:

`ip saddr 191.185.17.156 counter packets 100 bytes 4920`

`meter http size 65535 { ip saddr . tcp dport limit rate over 200/second } add @blocklist { ip saddr } counter packets 73 bytes 3576`

Now what's breaking my head, how is it possible to have 100 packets from my source IP to port 80 on the server, and at the same time there are 73 excess packets? Since 100 is less than 200, therefore the second counter should be empty

Not to mention that IPv4 has been added to the blocklist unduly.

Comment: cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756437/nftables-does-not-work-as-expected-to-block-with-meter (please check  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu )

Comment: @A.B Do you believe there could be a bug in nftables?